# Docker: Multiple networks, one container and ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have set up multiple containers in one docker compose file.

I want all containers to share a network. One container needs `network_mode: host`.

As I understand, adding `network_mode: host` to one container prevents this container from accessing the other containers which does not have network mode host.

So I tried to define two networks, one with driver `bridge` (network A) (all containers should be connected to this network) and one with driver `macvlan` (network B) (only the container that requires `network_mode: host` should be connected to this network).

In general, everything works as expected. The container which is connected to network B got an ip addres in my local network and can communicate with the other containers connected to network A.

The problem is, that the `ports` configuration seems to not work. I want to expose a port of the container connected to network A and B to all connected host networks. This doesn't work when I connect the container to network A and B.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need host networking for the one container?  That option generally disables Docker's networking stack entirely, and in fact, `ports:` won't have any effect on that container; you can't both be on the host network and also a Docker-internal network.

Comment: I need it for Home Assistant Core to work correctly: https://www.home-assistant.io/installation/raspberrypi#docker-compose